# using stringr to split vectors, unexpected result length

Tags: r, stringr

Something simple I'm messing up in using `stringr` to manipulate character vectors. I have a data frame of the following sort

```
library(stringr)
d1 <- data.frame(x = str_c(rpois(10, lambda=5), 
                           rpois(10, lambda=10),
                           sep = "_"))
```

and I want everything after the underscore as a separate variable. This use of `str_sub` results in a vector of length 20, and I'm at a loss to explain why.

```
d1$y <- str_sub(d1$x, str_locate(d1$x, fixed("_"))+1)
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = c("_12", "_7", "_15",  : 
>     replacement has 20 rows, data has 10

Could someone direct me how to write the `str_sub` call in the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want to be doing (check out output of `str_locate` to see why it wasn't working for you, also note that `str_sub` recycles the arguments):

```
d1$y = str_sub(d1$x, str_locate(d1$x, fixed("_"))[,1] + 1, -1)
```

Or in base R:

```
d1$y = sub("^[^_]*_", "", d1$x)
```